# Как ввернуться к началу цикла?

Tags: python, requests

Если сервер закрыт и не поступает запрос, он зачастую очень долго обрабатывает его и только потом выходит "Не верный ip". Так вот, как сделать так - что если я ввожу айпи сервера и он не правильный (очень долго грузит) - ввернуться обратно к вводу айпи?

при отправке запроса /ping там выходит pong насчет этого не волнуйтесь

```
ser = input('ip: ')
resp = requests.get(f'http://{ser}/ping')
if resp.text != 'pong':
    print('Не верный ip')
    exit()
else:
    print('Соединение установлено.')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно зациклить код и добавить ограничение на время через параметр `timeout`

Пример:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import Timeout

while True:
    ser = input('ip: ')
    try:
        resp = requests.get(f'http://{ser}/ping', timeout=5)
    except Timeout:
        continue
    
    if resp.text != 'pong':
        print('Неверный ip')
    else:
        print('Соединение установлено.')
    
    break
```

Comment: Да, можно и так, вы не правильно меня поняли. Я хочу чтобы допустим если в течении 5 секунд я не дождусь pong, то он меня отправляет обратно на input.

Comment: @debash, обновил ответ :)